# supervisorctl status report error: <class 'OSError'>, [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address: file: /usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py line: 797

Tags: python, supervisord

In a docker container, I started the supervisor process, and then when I check the status of the supervisor, I get this error:

```
root@6195a16dafd3:/etc/supervisor/conf.d# supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisor-app.conf                                                  
root@6195a16dafd3:/etc/supervisor/conf.d# supervisorctl status                           
error: <class 'OSError'>, [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address: file: /usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py line: 797`
```

A portion of supervisor-app.conf reads as follows：

```
[unix_http_server]                                                
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; path to your socket file                        
[supervisord]                                       
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; supervisord log file        
logfile_maxbytes=50MB       ; maximum size of logfile before rotation        
logfile_backups=10          ; number of backed up logfile                         
loglevel=info               ; info, debug, warn, trace         
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; pidfile location                              
nodaemon=false              ; run supervisord as a daemon                           
minfds=1024                 ; number of startup file descriptors                   
minprocs=200                ; number of process descriptors                           
user=root                   ; default user                     
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor/            ; where child log files will live 
[rpcinterface:supervisor]                                       
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface 
[supervisorctl]                                       
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock
```

The 797 line in /usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py is:

```
    host, port = address
    err = None
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
        sock = None
        try:
            sock = socket(af, socktype, proto)
            if timeout is not _GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT:
                sock.settimeout(timeout)
            if source_address:
                sock.bind(source_address)
            sock.connect(sa)    # 797 line
            # Break explicitly a reference cycle
            err = None
            return sock
```

How should I solve this problem?